# Spring Data Rest: How do I add logic before validation?

Tags: spring-data-rest

I need to massage some data before a javax validation on save is run. Using "beforeCreate" doesn't work because apparently the validator is called before the "beforeCreate" is. Is there another ApplicationEvent I can use?

Alternatively, can someone answer where I can place business logic in the Spring Data Rest framework? Usually there is a service layer, but they don't seem to exist in this infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. The RepositoryEventHandler and Validator are the hooks that you can work with. If you need more you have to fall back to custom Controllers.

From my point of view the RepositoryEventHandler methods would be the place to plug in up your business logic. You can have a service class as a central place to put your service logic and let the RepositoryEventHandler invoke it.

Why would you actually try to execute business logic before the validation takes place?

Comment: I need to load data in from the database to do a cross table validation.

Comment: You could use the spring data rest validation functions - Validators can be spring beans - so you could also access other repositories - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation